# Не вызывается repaint() для JPanel из actionPerformed()

Tags: java, swing

Код прекрасно работающий из метода go(), почему-то не хочет работать по нажатию на кнопку. Проблема в том, что метод repaint просто не вызывается, хотя цикл успешно пробегает по всем значениям. В чем может быть дело?

```
public class DisappearingRectangleByBook {
PanelWithRect panel;
int count = 1;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    DisappearingRectangleByBook dr = new DisappearingRectangleByBook();
    dr.go();
}

private void go() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Исчезающий прямоугольник");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    panel = new PanelWithRect();
    JButton button = new JButton("Пф-ф-ф");
    button.addActionListener(new MyButtonListener());

    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame.getContentPane().add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    frame.setSize(500, 270);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++, count++) {
        panel.repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class MyButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        count = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++, count++) {
            System.out.println(count);
            panel.repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

class PanelWithRect extends JPanel{
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.fillRect(count, count, 450 - count * 2, 200 - count * 2);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ActionListener.actionPerformed` выполняется в Event Dispatch Thread, а `repaint` ставит задание на перерисовку в конец очереди событий на обработку, т.е. перерисовка не выполнится, пока `actionPerformed` не завершится. Ваш метод `go()` выполняется в основном потоке приложения, поэтому перерисовка работает.

Чтобы анимация работала по кнопке, стартуйте отдельный поток, или используйте `javax.swing.Timer`. В случае с отдельным потоком, `count` стоит объявить, как `volatile`, чтобы избежать проблем с видимостью изменений. Либо можете вызвать `panel.getGraphics()` и рисовать на ней.

Comment: Мог бы и догадаться, что слушатель должен иметь отдельный поток. Но догадаться, что repaint() ставит задание в конец - навряд ли. Самое интересное, что и в конце он не каждый раз срабатывал... И почему это не пишут в учебниках?

Comment: @Yukon в учебниках, наверное, советуют в общем, не вызывать длительные операции в обработчиках событий.

Comment: Библиотека Swing не является потокобезопасной, поэтому любые манипуляции с компонентами, в том числе их создание, должны выполняться на Event Dispatch Thread'e (EDT).